# Distributions where geometric average of the weighted average equals the weights

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $a$ and $b$ be two non negative real number and $i$ and $j$ be two i.i.d. random variables. I'm trying to find the class of distributions (for $i$ and $j$) where
$$
\exp(E[\log(a\exp(i) + b\exp(j))]) = a + b
$$
would hold.

so far the only thing I came up with is that if $b= 0$,
$$\exp(E[\log(a\exp(i))]) = \exp(E[\log(a) + i)]) = \exp(\log(a) + E[i]) = a\exp(E[i]) = a $$
thus the first moment of that distribution has to be zero.

Comment: I have never seen people use $i$ and $j$ to denote two random variables... I would by all means avoid doing this.

Comment: that seems like the least important point of this question...